# React Material UI Autocomplete show options with issue

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I use Material UI Autocomplete. When user doesn't type 500ms, I send async request to get locations from backend, and then when I get response, I fetch and store the options onto redux store, and then my Autocomplete get options from store and show. I can type in many languages. In this case I type both in English and in Armenian. But, the response is the same, so in both languages the response is the same array of options. But in other languages(not English), the Autocomplete work with issue. The options aren't shown, and instead shows No Options. But the options are here, and you have just to click one time in autocomplete field, to see the options. Here is GIF animation how it works. The main thing is that in both cases, the response result is absolutely the same.[image: behavior]

Comment: Could you please give me an example of a language you are trying to work in that is not working. I have added a link below with a material ui autocomplete (which is currently experimental by the way) and I used chinese and dutch and they all seem to work. See if you can share code or use my code to give an example of what you are experiencing. 

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-7h7si

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I solved the problem. You have just to add filterOptions prop to Autocomplete. You can simply add a function "filterOptions={x => x}". And it will work.